# How to create view to display list of files in ASP.Net MVC 4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I am learning ASP.Net MVC 4 Programming. Currently, I want to display the list of files to the web page. Following is what I did till now.

In the `HomeController.cs` I edited the `Contact` action as follows:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
     ViewBag.Message = "Your file page.";
     DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
     List<string> filenames=dirInfo.GetFiles().Select(i=>i.Name).ToList();
     ViewBag.data = filenames; 
     ///^^ Is this correct??    

     return View();
}
```

I want the filenames to be displayed to the web page. What should I write in my view? I right clicked the `Contact` action and got the default view, containing:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}

<h2>Contact</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ChrisV wrote, you may want to create a strongly typed view. That means that you're associating a Model with your View. You would then pass the data using the `View()` overload which takes the Model as parameter. In your current version, you're sending data to the view using the `ViewBag`. That's not wrong, but it would be probably best to create a strongly typed view, at least as you go along learning.

That being said, I would probably do the following changes:

In your controller, get a list of `FileInfo` objects, instead of *file names*. The `FileInfo` type exposes additional features that you can use to enrich the displayed data.

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your file page.";
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
    List<FileInfo> files = dirInfo.GetFiles().ToList();

    //pass the data trough the "View" method
    return View(files);
}
```

Next, you need to specify the model type inside your view, and to iterate and display the data:

```
@model IEnumerable<FileInfo>

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}

<h2>Contact</h2>

<ul>
@foreach (FileInfo file in Model)
{
     <li>@file.Name</li>
}
</ul>
```

Please note, what and how you actually display on the page is up to you. You could create a table for the files and display the creation time, the size or even a command (download, delete, etc.). This is just a "template"; use it as such.

Comment: Honsetly, Its my first ASP.NET MVC 4 programming. And Since I am already enrolled to this class I need to understand the subject **on the fly**. I can't wait for whole book to finish and then start developing applications. So I am learning as per the chapter. Many thanks for your inputs..

Answer (score 1):

The primary thing you are displaying on the page (i.e. what the view is "for") should be the model. Look up the `@model` directive. Here it should be `@model List<string>`. Then instead of setting `ViewBag.data`, use `return View(filenames);`. In your view you will then be able to access a strongly-typed model. If there's anything you don't understand about what I just said, you need to read more about the role of a viewmodel in ASP.NET MVC.